# javascript, xml, query a file to see if tag==1 then do something

Tags: javascript, xml, if-statement, xml-parsing

How can I fix the code below to read the IsPublic data in the xml file and when IsPublic is equal to 1 ...print the Name and Url... else do nothing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
    });
});

function xmlParser(xml) {
    $(xml).find("Form").each(function (if "$this.IsPublic"==1) {
        $("#container").append('<div>' + 
            $(this).find("Name").text() + '<br/>' +
            $(this).find("Url").text() +
        '</div>');
    }else{});
}
</script>


//Example data in data.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Forms>
   <Form>
      <Name>BRIO Tuscan Grille</Name>
      <Description>Event descript Hosts: Persons name </Description>
      <RedirectMessage>Great! Thanks for filling out my form!</RedirectMessage>
      <Url>brio-tuscan-grille</Url>
      <Email>email@email.com</Email>
      <IsPublic>1</IsPublic>
      <Language>english</Language>
   </Form>
</Forms>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code have some syntax errors. When you fix them, it would be look like this:

```
function xmlParser(xml) {
    $("Form", xml).each(function () {
        if ($("IsPublic", xml).text()==1) {
            $("#container").append('<div>' + 
                $(this).find("Name").text() + '<br/>' +
                $(this).find("Url").text() +
            '</div>');
        };
    });
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sKy4k/

Answer (score 0):

Kreozot, you were very close and gave me the direction I needed Thx.
the only problem was IsPublic wasn't actually reading the individual items.
I jumped over to your jsfiddle link and came up with this and it seems to work now.
Thanks again!

```
function xmlParser(xml) {
    $("Form", xml).each(function () {
        if ($(this).find("IsPublic").text()==1) {
            $("#container").append('<div>' + 
                                   $(this).find("Name").text() + '<br/>' +
                                   $(this).find("Url").text() +
                                   '</div>');
        };
    });
};
```